# Trouble Making AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish with AJAX. I've never used AJAX before so I'm not even sure what I'm trying to accomplish is the correct use.  I'm trying to speed up the rate at which users of my site can delete certain messages that accumulate in their inbox.  In previous versions of my site, the page had to refresh every time you deleted a message which can get to be pretty slow.  To fix this I decided that instead of triggering a form when the user pressed the "Delete" button, I would set up jquery on the client side to erase the message html and then send an asynchronous POST request telling the server to delete the message from the database.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".deleteButton").click(function() {
           var id = $(this).attr('id');
           $("tr#"+id).slideUp("fast");
           $.ajax({type: "post",
                 url: "/message",
                 data: {"delete_mes": id}});
    });
});
```

This almost works.  Whenever I click delete the message disappears and when I reload the page it is still gone, showing that the server successfully deleted the message.  However, when I delete more than one message before reloading the page, all of the messages but the first one reappear.

Hopefully someone with more experience in ajax will know whats wrong.  My server is set up with Google App Engine.  Thanks!

Comment: It appears as though you have duplicate ID's, i'd suggest fixing that first.

Comment: Wouldn't that just delete more than one instead of not enough?

Comment: I don't know, since using invalid html can have *unpredictable* results.

Comment: Although, this particular part doesn't make any sense: *"Whenever I click delete the message disappears and when I reload the page it is still gone, showing that the server successfully deleted the message. However, when I delete more than one message before reloading the page, the messages reappear."* If removing one works, then removing two should at least work for the first one. did you mean to say that all other than the first fail to delete?

Comment: The only thing i see wrong with your code is the duplicate ID issue. If fixing that doesn't solve it, the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I did mean that all but the first one appear.  Sorry for the lack of clarity :).  I changed the ids to classes and it works!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First: You should not use the same id more then once on the page.

I've made a solution for you, check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLAH2/1/).

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".deleteButton").click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent('tr');
        var id = parent.attr('id');
        parent.slideUp("fast");
        // your ajax
    });
});
```

Comment: The question got resolved before I managed to try out your solution but thanks anyway!